# Dynamic page for nav items used as filters

Tags: custom-post-types, php, filters, hooks

I have a bunch of nav items and each of those items are used as a "filter",
this filter means that when clicked the user should go to a page that has only the items matched with the filter clicked, my question is: how can i achieve the creation of the page per filter and the showing of the results?

P.S: Those filters show a custom post type with 1 taxonomy (the filter name)

Comment: When editing the menu you should be able to add your taxonomy terms to the menu. That's all you should need to do, if everything else is set up correctly. If it's not appearing, please share your code for registering the post type and taxonomy.

Comment: @JacobPeattie my question ir more directed towards the creation of the dynamic pages, sorry if i wasnt clear, im kinda confused on how can i achieve this

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic pages"? Your question asks about linking to pages that filter posts by taxonomy term. This should be the default behaviour when viewing the link to a taxonomy term. So there's no need to create 'dynamic' pages. If you actually want to create 'dynamic' pages for another purpose you need to actually ask a question about that, with information about what you're trying to do. There's no generic answer.